# having truble with upgrade to 0.57.1 react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

im upgrading my react native project from 0.54.6 to 0.57.1 and im giving this error in my pckager

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: The 'decorators' plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean. If you are migrating from Babylon/Babel 6 or want to use the old decorators proposal, you should use the 'decorators-legacy' plugin instead of 'decorators'.
    at validatePlugins (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project\upgrade\project\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10424:13)    at getParser (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project upgrade\project\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10481:5)
    at parse (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project upgrade\project\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10452:20)
    at parser (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\projectupgrade\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\normalize-file.js:170:34)
    at normalizeFile (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project upgrade\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\normalize-file.js:138:11)
    at runSync (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project upgrade\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:44:43)
    at transformSync (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project upgrade\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:43:38)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project upgrade\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\reactNativeTransformer.js:153:5)
    at C:\Users\pimi-laptop\Desktop\project upgrade\project\node_modules\metro-config\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:182:23
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2018:08:30:05 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.10.0"
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

and this is my .babelrc look like

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

im try to install latest version of babel but im not sure thats work or im doing it correct

my project build succefully but my packager dont load to the end and it stuck with this error

thanks for advance.